# How can I use the attribute selector with :not

Tags: css, syntax

I want to select every element that's not a `input[type="text"]` however apparently this doesn't work:

```
:not(input[type="text"]) { ... }
```

But this does:

```
:not(input) { ... }
```

How can I include the attribute `[]` selector with a `:not`?

Comment: "every element that's not a `input[type="text"]`"

Answer (score 1):

```
:not([type='text']) {    
    /* other codes */
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: "every element that's not a input[type="text"]"

Comment: How does it know it's not an input